# Laravel saving to database when running unit tests

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5, phpunit, functional-testing

Im attempting to run a Laravel functional test, using the Model Factory to create some test data.

On other tests, within the same directory and namespace, using similar 'make' traits, no entries are saved in the database. But with this one they are.

When using `app('env')` it returns `'testing'`, so the environment is correct.

Any ideas on how I can run these tests without saving to the mySQL database?

**RoleTest**

```
namespace Tests;

use Tests\Traits\MakeRoleTrait;

class RoleTest extends BrowserKitTestCase
{
    use MakeRoleTrait;

    public function testGetChildren()
    {
        $childRoles = [];
        $baseRoles = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            $parentId = null;

            if($i > 0){
                $parentId = $baseRoles[$i-1]->id;
            }

            $childRole = $this->makeRole();

            // Create base role
            $baseRoles[] =  $this->makeRole([
                'parent_id' => $parentId,
                'display_name' => $childRole->display_name,
                'site_id' => null
            ]);

            if($i < 3){
                $childRoles[] = $childRole;
            }
        }

        $children = $childRoles[0]->getChildren();

        $this->assertEquals($childRoles,$children);
    }
}
```

**MakeRoleTrait**

```
namespace Tests\Traits;


use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Repositories\RoleRepository;

trait MakeRoleTrait
{
    /**
     * Create fake instance of Role and save it in database
     *
     * @param array $roleFields
     * @return Role
     */
    public function makeRole($roleFields = [])
    {
        /** @var RoleRepository $roleRepo */
        $roleRepo = \App::make(RoleRepository::class);
        $theme = $this->fakeRoleData($roleFields);
        return $roleRepo->skipPresenter()->create($theme);
    }

    /**
     * Get fake instance of Role
     *
     * @param array $roleFields
     * @return Role
     */
    public function fakeRole($roleFields = [])
    {
        return new Role($this->fakeRoleData($roleFields));
    }

    /**
     * Get fake data of Role
     *
     * @param array $roleFields
     * @return array
     */
    public function fakeRoleData($roleFields = [])
    {
        $role = factory(\App\Models\Role::class,1)->make();
        $array = $role->first()->toArray();

        $array = array_merge(
            $array,
            $roleFields
        );

        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="..."/>` in `phpunit.xml` should tell Laravel which connection to use while testing. It should be a separate connection to the main app, so it runs its queries there instead. Make sure `env('DB_CONNECTION')` has an effect on your `config/database.php` , too

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I dont think this is what Im looking for. The DB_CONNECTION in all of my other tests are set to mysql just like it is in this one, but the other tests dont save to the database. There is no line in my phpunit.xml for DB_CONNECTION, hence its defaulting to mysql.

Comment: You really should have the tests run on a separate database. That said, maybe the other tests are using the [refresh database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) traits? Or if it's an older version of Laravel, one of the style `DatabaseTransactions` traits that perform a rollback every time?

Comment: Thats the one! Set this as your answer, Ill explain and accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has traits to roll-back changes made to the database. In 5.6, it's [the `RefreshDatabase` trait](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) - in some earlier versions [it was `DatabaseTransactions` instead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test).

These traits should be added to all tests that make database updates/inserts.

(For additional ease (and safety), tests should run on a separate database connection with a separate copy of the database, too.)